# Pages reload on resize, on scroll, and on keyboard pop up in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a list that reads data from Firebase, when I scroll through the images list (mobile) or resize the page (desktop) provided from the database, it reloads and shows a blank page for a few seconds, then the lists start from the top.

It only reloads the part of the website that is loaded from the database, other parts of the webpage are not reloaded. This list contains URLs to images.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('users').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const users = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          users.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
        setSLimy(users);
        setLoading(false);
      });

    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);
```

**HTML**

```
<List component="ul">
  {slimy.map(function(item){
    return (
      <CustomItem key={item.createdAt} Description={item.Description} Image={item.Image} />
    )
  })}
</List>
```

**CustomItem function**

```
const CustomItem = (item) => {
  return(<ListItem key={item.createdAt} ><img src={item.Image} alt={item.Description}/><p>{item.Description}</p>)
```

Text inputs also reload the whole page (shows a blank page for a few seconds) when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: no answer yet? 